# Время выполнения запроса

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Есть такой запрос

```
SELECT
  cls.ID
FROM
  clusters cls
  JOIN station_clusters stn_cls ON (
    cls.ID = stn_cls.CLUSTER_ID
  )
WHERE
  cls.ZOOM = 16 AND
  cls.LATITUDE BETWEEN 50.4517132797654 AND 50.46219141542923 AND
  cls.LONGITUDE BETWEEN 30.414679388109086 AND 30.443218092028292
```

Он вытягивает 128 записей. Время его выполнения с этими в одной сессии с одними и теми же параметрами составляет 0.109 или 2.187 секунд. Вопрос, почему так пляшет время? Если убрать JOIN то получаю время выполнения около нуля.

DDL таблиц

```sql
  CREATE TABLE "ANTON"."CLUSTERS" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LATITUDE" BINARY_DOUBLE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LONGITUDE" BINARY_DOUBLE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ZOOM" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_CLUSTERS" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

  CREATE INDEX "ANTON"."IDX_CLUSTERS_COORD" ON "ANTON"."CLUSTERS" ("ZOOM", "LATITUDE", "LONGITUDE") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;


  CREATE TABLE "ANTON"."STATION_CLUSTERS" 
   (    "STN_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "STN_SYS_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CLUSTER_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_STATION_CLUSTERS" PRIMARY KEY ("STN_ID", "STN_SYS_ID", "CLUSTER_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_STATION_CLUSTERS_STATIONS" FOREIGN KEY ("STN_ID", "STN_SYS_ID")
      REFERENCES "ANTON"."STATIONS" ("ID", "SYS_ID") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_STATION_CLUSTERS_CLUSTER" FOREIGN KEY ("CLUSTER_ID")
      REFERENCES "ANTON"."CLUSTERS" ("ID") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
```

Общее количество записей

- clusters  28341
- station_clusters  234332

План запроса

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если добавить еще один джойн, то время увеличивается до 8 секунд (и тоже через раз). Хочется понять причины такого поведения и, по возможности, устранить их

Comment: Надо посмотреть планы для запросов выполняющихся за разное время. Если планы различные, то понять, что меняется. Если планы одинаковые, то проблемы вообще не в запросе, а чем то еще. Например разной  нагрузкой на БД

Comment: Ну и еще. Если у вас первое выполнение 2 секунды, а второе 0.1 то все дело в том, то оракл держит в оперативе ваши данные. А возможно даже закешировал результат запроса

Comment: @Viktorov Я запрос выполняю непосредственно в SQL Developer. Просто один за другим. В одной транзакции. И время меняется через один. Оракл же не может держать данные ровно один запрос? Можно как-то отключить кеш, чтобы сравнять разные выполнения? Ну и две секунды для такого запроса все равно много

Comment: у вас БД чем то еще нагружена?

Comment: @Viktorov нет. Можно где-то посмотреть ститстику, чем занимается оракл?

Comment: Надо избавляться от FULL INDEX SCAN по PK_STATION_CLUSTERS, а для этого нужен индекс где это поле будет первым (или единственным). В зависимости от размера таблицы это полное сканирование может вытеснять из кеша что то полезное

Comment: @Mike так есть же индекс `CONSTRAINT "CONSTRAINT "FK_STATION_CLUSTERS_CLUSTER" FOREIGN KEY ("CLUSTER_ID")` или в Оракле внешний ключ индексом не является?

Comment: В принципе да, индекс должен быть. Меня этот full scan смущает, не понимаю зачем он тут вообще

Comment: @Mike такое ощущение, что берется первый индекс, в котором присутствует  это поле. `PK_STATION_CLUSTERS` в плане вообще быть не должно

Comment: Вроде ведь индекс по умолчанию при создании FK не создается. Нет возможости сейчас проверить

Comment: @Viktorov Допустим. Создал его руками. План не поменялся

Comment: У вас в индексе `PK_STATION_CLUSTERS` поле `CLUSTER_ID` на 3 месте. Кажется, что если вы добавите индекс по `CLUSTER_ID` то план должен переключиться на него. Какой индекс вы создали руками?

Comment: Чем вообще вызван такой порядок полей в PK. Возможно вам просто следует `CLUSTER_ID` поставить на 1 место?

Comment: @Viktorov Отдельный индекс на CLUSTER_ID `CREATE INDEX "FK_STATION_CLUSTERS_CLUSTER_IDX" ON "STATION_CLUSTERS" ("CLUSTER_ID")`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92517/discussion-between-viktorov-and-anton-shchyrov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При помощи советов [@Viktorov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179846/) проблема была решена.

1. Oracle, действительно не создает индексов на внешние ключи. Если индексы нужны, нужно их создавать самому. Однако добавление индекса

   ```
   CREATE INDEX "FK_STATION_CLUSTERS_CLUSTER_IDX" ON "STATION_CLUSTERS" ("CLUSTER_ID")
   ```

   на план особо не повлияло

   ```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
   | Id |     Operation     |        Name        |Rows|Bytes| Cost (%CPU)|   Time   | 
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
   | 0  | SELECT STATEMENT  |                    | 1  |  51 |    2 (0)   | 00:00:01 | 
   | 1  | NESTED LOOPS      |                    | 1  |  51 |    2 (0)   | 00:00:01 | 
   | 2  | NESTED LOOPS      |                    | 1  |  51 |    2 (0)   | 00:00:01 | 
   | 3  | TABLE ACCESS FULL | STATION_CLUSTERS   | 1  |  13 |    2 (0)   | 00:00:01 | 
   |* 4 | INDEX RANGE SCAN  | IDX_CLUSTERS_COORD | 1  |     |    0 (0)   | 00:00:01 | 
   |* 5 | TABLE ACCESS BY   | CLUSTERS           | 1  |  38 |    0 (0)   | 00:00:01 | 
   |    |       INDEX ROWID |                    |    |     |            |          |
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

   Predicate Information (identified by operation id): 
   --------------------------------------------------- 

   4 - access("CLS"."ZOOM"=16 AND "CLS"."LATITUDE">=5.04517132797654E+001D AND 
   "CLS"."LONGITUDE">=3.0414679388109086E+001D AND "CLS"."LATITUDE"<=5.0462191415429231E+001D 
   AND "CLS"."LONGITUDE"<=3.0443218092028292E+001D) 
   filter("CLS"."LONGITUDE">=3.0414679388109086E+001D AND 
   "CLS"."LONGITUDE"<=3.0443218092028292E+001D) 
   5 - filter("CLS"."ID"="STN_CLS"."CLUSTER_ID")
   ```
2. Тут обратили внимание, что оракл считает, что в таблицах находится по одной записи. После пересчета статистики по обоим таблицам

   ```
   exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname => 'ANTON', tabname =>'CLUSTERS', no_invalidate => false);
   exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname => 'ANTON', tabname =>'STATION_CLUSTERS', no_invalidate => false);
   ```

   план запроса изменился

   ```
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
   | Id |       Operation       |              Name               | Rows  | Bytes| Cost (%CPU)|   Time   | 
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
   | 0  | SELECT STATEMENT      |                                 | 34186 | 968K |   212 (4)  | 00:00:01 | 
   |* 1 |  HASH JOIN            |                                 | 34186 | 968K |   212 (4)  | 00:00:01 | 
   |* 2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL   | CLUSTERS                        | 4156  | 99744|    69 (2)  | 00:00:01 | 
   | 3  |   INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| FK_STATION_CLUSTERS_CLUSTER_IDX | 234K  | 1144K|   140 (3)  | 00:00:01 | 
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

   Predicate Information (identified by operation id): 
   --------------------------------------------------- 

   1 - access("CLS"."ID"="STN_CLS"."CLUSTER_ID") 
   2 - filter("CLS"."ZOOM"=16 AND "CLS"."LATITUDE">=5.04517132797654E+001D AND 
   "CLS"."LATITUDE"<=5.0462191415429231E+001D AND "CLS"."LONGITUDE">=3.0414679388109086E+001D AND 
   "CLS"."LONGITUDE"<=3.0443218092028292E+001D) 

   Note 
   ----- 
   - this is an adaptive plan`
   ```

   в таблице появились записи, стал использоваться созданный индекс и время выполнения запроса стало стабильно ~0

По поводу, почему же изначально плавало время выполнения, то [@Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/) выдвинул предположение, что полное сканирование таблицы просто вытесняет предварительно сохраненный кеш